# Is there any Atom Editor's plugin for Gitlab CE snippets creating and editing

Tags: gitlab, code-snippets, atom-editor

Is there any Atom Editor's plugin for Gitlab CE **snippets** creating and editing, something like [Gist-it](https://atom.io/packages/gist-it) which is a plugin for creating editing http://gist.github.com file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an *Visual Studio Code* Extension [Share Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RolandGreim.sharecode) , which supports GitLab.

GitLab **Access Token** will be asked to insert.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need a third-party editor for GitLab snippets anymore.

With [GitLab 13.0 (May 2020)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/05/22/gitlab-13-0-released/#improved-snippets-editor), you now have:

> ### Improved Snippets editor
>
> With the release of **[Versioned Snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33909274/6309)** in GitLab 13.0, **we’ve upgraded the Snippets editor to a lighter-weight version of the editor found in our Web IDE**.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_0/phikai-snippets-editor-improvements.gif]
>
> With this editor, users will benefit from **basic code completion** and **linting** for some languages.
> We’ve also improved source code language detection for **better syntax highlighting**, and added support for all our syntax highlighting themes.
>
> These improvements will make it easier to edit and collaborate on Snippets.
>
> We’re excited to bring consistency to the editors in Snippets and the Web IDE.
> In a future release we’ll expand this functionality to our single file editor and in our `.gitlab-ci.yml` editing experiences.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/snippets.html) and [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/198604).

---

Will [GitLab 13.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/01/22/gitlab-13-8-released/#ci-lint-tool-in-the-pipeline-editor-page) (January 2021), this extends to `gitlab-ci.yml` (pipelines)

> ### CI lint tool in the pipeline editor page
>
> The CI lint tool validates your pipeline syntax and provides you with some details about each job. Previously, CI lint was located on the jobs page which was difficult to find and access. In this release, accessing this tool is much easier than before because it is now included as a part of the new Pipeline Editor. With this improvement, you can easily use CI lint while editing your configuration and quickly validate that your syntax is what you want before committing the changes.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_8/lint.gif -- CI lint tool in the pipeline editor page]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/index.html#lint-ci-configuration) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/263147).

And the result of this internal editor being:

Still with [GitLab 13.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/01/22/gitlab-13-8-released/#visualization-of-pipeline-configuration) (January 2021)

> ### Visualization of pipeline configuration
>
> A complex CI configuration can be difficult to understand as a developer, especially when trying to predict how your pipeline might behave (or misbehave). Without a visual aid, it is challenging to form a mental image of the relationships between all of the jobs and determine how they are interconnected. In our first iteration of a pipeline visualization, you can now see a graphic representation of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration to better understand and predict how your pipelines will perform.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_8/pipeline_visual_builder.png -- Visualization of pipeline configuration]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/visualization.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/241722).

---

See also [GitLab 13.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/04/22/gitlab-13-11-released/#create-initial-configuration-file-from-the-pipeline-editor) (April 2021)

> ### Create initial configuration file from the pipeline editor
>
> The pipeline editor is your one stop shop to build and test your CI/CD pipeline.
>
> **Previously, the editor only worked if the `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration file already existed in the root of your repository**.
>
> In this release, we’ve added the ability to create an initial empty pipeline file from the pipeline editor page itself, so you can start authoring your pipeline immediately.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_11/empty.png -- Create initial configuration file from the pipeline editor]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/index.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/300059).

---

The pipeline editor improves with [GitLab 14.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/02/22/gitlab-14-8-released/#auto-completion-of-keywords-in-the-pipeline-editor) (February 2022)

> ### Auto-completion of keywords in the Pipeline Editor
>
> Writing a valid GitLab CI/CD pipeline can be difficult regardless of whether you’re a novice or more advanced user.
> Syntax structure should be accurate and even a small typo or misconfiguration could cause your pipeline to be invalid, introducing more work to find the source of the problem.
>
> In this release, we’ve added auto-completion of CI/CD keywords to the pipeline editor, which will greatly increase your efficiency when writing and debugging pipelines.
> You’ll be more confident that your pipeline will run the way you want it the very first time it runs.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/index.html#validate-ci-configuration) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/5246).