# How to programmatically access the full snippet in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, git-clone, gitlab-api

#### Question

My end goal is to have an offline, updateable copy of my snippets (including title & description) such that I can search and use them easily. How can I get all my snippets from Gitlab to my local machine?
I'm using Gitlab version is `13.12.10-ee`.

#### What I've looked into

##### Cloning snippets

It's possible to [clone snippet contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33906431/1256347) in Gitlab, but this only includes the file associated with the snippet. The title and description are excluded.

E.g. when I do `git clone git@company.gitlab.com:snippets/$snippet_id.git` I only receive the files associated with the snippet, not the title and the description:

[image]

I've checked the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/snippets.html#versioned-snippets) but could not find any mention of interacting with the description through git.

##### Gitlab API

I found that the Gitlab API has a [snippets](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/snippets.html#get-a-single-snippet) endpoint. However, when I use the [python-gitlab CLI tool](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli-objects.html#gitlab-snippet) and request a single snippet with `gitlab snippet get --id 123` I only get the ID and the title.
When I do `gitlab snippet content --id 123` I only get the contents of the file associated with the snippet.

Comment: Soooo `curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/snippets/123"` ? The documentation comes with an example. `could not find any mention of interacting with the description` It's right in the answer: `"description": "Ruby test snippet",`.

Comment: Soooo, no I didn't use that command as I use the python-gitlab CLI tool to interface with the gitlab API. It does return the description indeed, unfortunately I need to postprocess it to extract the description. If you want you can make it an answer though, thanks!

Comment: it can do that for you, just `gitlab -f description`, but it's better to use some json parser anyway

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand the use of the `-f` parameter as it only works in combination with the json or yaml output. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: Would be great the snippet content is just a by convention file like `README.md`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### From a Unix shell, using [CuRL](https://curl.se/) and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```sh
GITLAB_API_TOKEN=<your_api-scoped_token>
SNIPPET_ID=<snippet_id_number>

# Parse the JSON for the fields you want (.title,.description)
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_API_TOKEN" \
  "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/snippets/$SNIPPET_ID" \
  | jq '.title,.description'

# Use the /raw endpoint to get the full snippet content
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_API_TOKEN" \
  "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/snippets/$SNIPPET_ID/raw
```

### Using [python-gitlab](https://gitlab.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab):

```py
import gitlab
GITLAB_API_TOKEN=<your_api-scoped_token>
SNIPPET_ID=<snippet_id_number>

gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.example.com', private_token=GITLAB_API_TOKEN)
snippet = gl.snippets.get(SNIPPET_ID)
title = snippet.title
descr = snippet.description
cont  = snippet.content()
```